# print_req_error: I/O error, dev loop0, sector xxxxxxx - ошибка при запуске ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Я решил установить убунту, и я смог установить убунту.
На данный момент он стоит рядом с *windows 7*.
Устанавливал его я с помощью `wubi`, для ubuntu я отдельно создал раздел на диске (U:).
Ubuntu хорошо работал, запускался, но сейчас при запуске вот такая ошибка:

> print_req_error: I/O error dev loop0, sector xxxxxxx

(x - какие-то цифры).
И таких строчек 10.
ПЖ помогите решить эту проблему (сразу я скажу что я не особо разбираюсь в линуксе...)

Comment: Request (запрос) на обращение к устройству петли выпадает в осадок. Одна из причин может быть, что реальный storage за loop в не совсем хорошем состоянии.

Comment: И что же мне тогда делать?...